# SSRS Reports Fail To Render in Dynamic CRM

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, render, crm, bids

I am creating reports in SSRS BIDs and then deploying them in Dynamic CRM 2015 however some reports will generate the parameter header but after params have been chosen and click 'View Report' it completely fails to render or generate any content.

No error is showing and the report runs perfectly fine in Reporting Services.

Any suggestions or signpost to troubleshooting sites would be appreciated.

Comment: Do your out of the box reports work? Did you check the logs on the SSRS server or look at the trace logs?

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM I found the logs but they don't mean much to me. I've had a bug raised today where a previously working report now doesn't.